# After inserting into database the string ' ə' becomes question marks with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, database, utf-8, decode

I'm inserting strings into a SQL Server database, the type is `text`, some of the characters become question marks.

I know this is a decode issue,but don't know how to solve it.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    for i in words:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words (word) VALUES(?)", i)
```

Result:

The character 'ə' becomes '?'

Comment: Maybe use BINARY keyword?

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: If you want to store **Unicode** text - then you need to use **Unicode** datatype - .`NVARCHAR(n)` (or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for really extremely large columns)

Comment: *if* `varchar(max)` works, then `text` would have too...